# bandwidth/QOS test - paid or free

Tags: video-streaming, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling, qos

I have to support a video rich web site. Many of the users are on a city/municipal computer and network.  When a user reports a performance issue (video slow to load or hanging) we verify server and backbone and multiple endpoints.  We are working on redesign for media to coem from a conetnt delivery network structure but I still need a good tool to ask the end user to run to verify their ability from inside of their firewall consume videos.

Is there a service or a package i can install on my microsoft IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the providers of web speedtests support a version you can integrate into your own site. For example:

- http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php
- http://www.broadbandspeedtest.co.uk/about/